# Refining Tin (Sn)

Tags: metallurgy, purification

I am a Copper Cookware Tinner & have a problem in reusing much of the tin that I end up sweeping off the floor etc. Prob about 5kg over the year & it would be great to save this?

Now, my workshop will definitely have copper dust around the place & possibly other metals?

What is happening when I re melt all the sweepings is that I am getting a casting of tin that is not quite all tin I believe? Instead of nice flat crystalline structure, I am getting long needle like crystals. This I am told is due to some copper being percent in the finished metal? I have heard this can be cleaned/removed using sulfur?

As you can probably tell from the terms I am using, I am no scientist, but I would be very grateful in learning the practical aspects of getting this tin back to near 999 grade as I originally receive it

Comment: No expert in refining metals, but I can't imagine that the extra equipment, chemicals, and time to refine the tin would be worth it financially. Also you'd need some way in the end to analyze the tin to be sure of its purity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MaxW. Was kind of hoping the sulfur method was simply a case of adding it to the pot and this smoking off the copper or something like that????
The problem is that the tin with probably less than 1% copper in it is not the same crystalline structure as 999 tin & will not be non stick as tin is.
Will keep checking here & possibly its not too hard to accomplish this?
All the best, Steve

Comment: Even if you could "smoke off" the copper as you suggest, it seems like a poor idea. Smelting is plain nasty. Putting a metal in the atmosphere should give you pause. You would also get sulfur, sulfur oxides and who knows what else. So you'd really need an exotic setup to do something like that safely.

Comment: Cheers Max. Although I am still looking for the practice instruction on how to do this. Its nothing new and has been easily accomplished for thousands of years with only the most basic of equipment.
I figure a Volcano pumps a fair bit of these type of things out every now and then!?